# Static IP Address with NetworkManager for Fedora

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager, fedora-19

I just wanted to set up a static IP address for a fedora 19 machine in my LAN. I'm used to `/etc/network/interfaces` from debian but that file doesn't exist here.
After googling around a little bit, I found a small tutorial that tells one to disable NetworkManager via systemctl and enable network. After that one could configure the static IP address in a file called `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*interfacename*`.

Here is my first problem: I found a file with the MAC address of my interface as displayed by `ifconfig` but the name after ifcfg- doesn't match the name from ifconfig. Why is that like this?

My second problem is about using NetworkManager.service or network.service. I read in a Forum, that network.service is still included for compatibility reasons and may be excluded soon. If network.service will soon be replaced by NetworkManager.service, shouldn't I choose NetworkManager.service to configure my network interfaces? If yes, how do I do that with NetworkManager from a shell?

Edit:
Here are the outputs requested:

```
[root@bitch /]# ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 97  bytes 12042 (11.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 97  bytes 12042 (11.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p3p1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::214:85ff:febc:1c63  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:14:85:bc:1c:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 134347  bytes 169988336 (162.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78199  bytes 6595669 (6.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 1  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@bitch /]# ls -l /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
total 200
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   437 Sep 15 02:05 ifcfg-enp2s5
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   254 May 31 09:49 ifcfg-lo
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    24 Jun 27 19:12 ifdown -> ../../../usr/sbin/ifdown
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   627 May 31 09:49 ifdown-bnep
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  5553 May 31 09:49 ifdown-eth
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   781 May 31 09:49 ifdown-ippp
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  4141 May 31 09:49 ifdown-ipv6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    11 Jun 27 19:12 ifdown-isdn -> ifdown-ippp
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1642 May 31 09:49 ifdown-post
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1068 May 31 09:49 ifdown-ppp
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   837 May 31 09:49 ifdown-routes
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1444 May 31 09:49 ifdown-sit
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1462 May 31 09:49 ifdown-tunnel
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    22 Jun 27 19:12 ifup -> ../../../usr/sbin/ifup
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 12445 May 31 09:49 ifup-aliases
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   859 May 31 09:49 ifup-bnep
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10234 May 31 09:49 ifup-eth
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 12033 May 31 09:49 ifup-ippp
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10437 May 31 09:49 ifup-ipv6
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   804 May 31 09:49 ifup-ipx
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 Jun 27 19:12 ifup-isdn -> ifup-ippp
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   642 May 31 09:49 ifup-plip
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1043 May 31 09:49 ifup-plusb
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2609 May 31 09:49 ifup-post
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  4154 May 31 09:49 ifup-ppp
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1925 May 31 09:49 ifup-routes
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3268 May 31 09:49 ifup-sit
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  2607 May 31 09:49 ifup-tunnel
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3775 May 31 09:49 ifup-wireless
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  4623 May 31 09:49 init.ipv6-global
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 13836 May 31 09:49 network-functions
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 26134 May 31 09:49 network-functions-ipv6
```

Content of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s5:

```
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6INIT="yes"
NAME="enp2s5"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
DEFROUTE="yes"
UUID="7622e20e-3f2a-4b5c-83d8-f4f6e22ed7ec"
PEERDNS="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
HWADDR="00:14:85:BC:1C:63"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
TYPE="Ethernet"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPADDR=192.168.178.11
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BROADCAST=192.168.178.255
NETWORK=192.168.178.0
GATEWAY=192.168.178.1
```

Grepping dmesg for udevd:

```
[root@bitch network-scripts]# dmesg | grep udevd
[    0.788381] systemd-udevd[97]: starting version 204
[    2.457296] systemd-udevd[322]: starting version 204
[    3.110272] systemd-udevd[329]: renamed network interface eth0 to p3p1
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of the folloring two commands 1) `ls /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` 2) `ifconfig`

Comment: I know you said you wanted to do it from a command shell, but I posted an answer detailing how to do it with the graphical interface. If you post the output of the 2 commands I mentioned in the previous comment, I will revise my answer to help with doing it via the command shell.

Comment: I will post them, just a sec.

Comment: I feel like `p3p1` is configured as an alias, and `enp2s5` is the real name. What about the output from `grep -e "NAME=\|HWADDR=" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s5`? Is the value of `NAME=` equal to `enp2s5` or `p3p1`?

Comment: The variable name might be `DEVICE` instead of `NAME`...

Comment: Something else that could help is `dmesg | grep udevd`

Comment: I've edited again. "NAME" in enp2s5 is set to enp2s5. No alias here. dmesg says, udevd has renamed eth0 to enp2s5. Still no clue where p3s1 comes from...

Comment: `udevd` is the service that is responsible for assigning "predictable names" to network devices. It is renaming `eth0` to `p3p1` which is the current name as displayed by `ifconfig`. So, something is going where in creating your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` files. I'm still looking for where those names actually get pulled from.

Comment: The output `dmesg | grep enp2s5`  could reveal what is causing the network-scripts to use `enp2s5` instead of `p3p1` (which is what it should be using).

Comment: I'd be interested to see what happens if you rename `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s5` to `ifcfg-p3p1` and change `NAME=enp2s5` to `NAME=p3p1` (basically, rename the network-script to use the device name from `ifconfig`). But you said you only accessed this through SSH, so I don't want to suggest anything that might prevent you from getting back into the PC/Server.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution, I believe will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Command-Line Instructions

After much digging, I found that the **ifcfg-*** file names, and the `NAME=` variable in the file have very little to do with the actual assignment. You can literally change them to whatever you want... I did a test on my machine changing them to `eth0` and the manual/static IP was still applied upon startup. The key here seems to the be `HWADDR` variable inside the file. The `NAME=` value only seems to be the name displayed in the graphical Network Manager settings. So, that being said I believe all you need to do is...

1. Make sure `NetworkManager.service` is still enabled, and `network.service` is disabled.
2. The most **IMPORTANT** step is to delete the current **ifcfg-enp2s5** script.

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s5
   ```
3. Create a new script named **ifcfg-p3p1**

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-p3p1
   ```
4. Set the contents of **ifcfg-p3p1** to the following, and update the respective IP settings with your desired settings.

   ```
   TYPE=Ethernet
   BOOTPROTO=none
   DEFROUTE=yes
   IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   IPV6INIT=yes
   IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
   IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
   IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   NAME=p3p1
   UUID=7622e20e-3f2a-4b5c-83d8-f4f6e22ed7ec
   ONBOOT=yes
   DNS1=10.0.0.1
   IPADDR0=10.0.0.2
   PREFIX0=24
   GATEWAY0=10.0.0.1
   HWADDR=00:14:85:BC:1C:63
   IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
   IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
   ```

As for why the **ifcfg-*** name was different from the actual device name. I don't know but suspect it has something to do with how the Network settings were applied during installation.

### Graphical Instructions

1. Open **System Settings**
2. Click on **Network**
3. Click on **Options...**
4. Click on the **IPv4 Settings*** or **IPv6 Settings** tab depending on what IP version your home network is using (most likely **IPv4**).
5. Click on the **Method** combo-box and select the **Manual** option.
6. Click on the **Add** button.
7. Type the address you want in the **Address** columns (e.g. 10.0.0.20).
8. Type the netmask for your network in the **Netmask** column (e.g. 255.255.255.0).
9. Enter the gateway (usually your router's IP) in the **Gateway** column (e.g. 10.0.0.1)
10. Enter your DNS server in the **DNS servers** text-box (e.g. 10.0.0.1)

    [image: Wired Connection Options Dialog]
11. Click on **Save...**
12. When you return to the **Network** settings, turn the **Wired** interface **OFF**.
13. It should automatically turn back on with the static address information you entered in the previous steps. If it does not turn on, click the toggle switch to turn it on.

    [image: Network Settings After Manual IP Selection]

---

To answer your question about using the `NetworkManager.service` over `network.service`. There is definitely potential it could be removed in later releases. As a general rule of thumb though, no matter the topic is, you should always try to avoid using anything *"included for backwards compatibility"*. So, you should stick to using `NetworkManager` *if you can*.

Comment: because I control this machine over SSH. GUI stuff is no solution. That's why I wanted a solution to configure NetworkManager on a shell and I'm also wondering why the network service should be replaced despite it's easy configurable from the shell.

Comment: And for your rule of thumb: That's why I ask about using one of these two, but I need to use a shell-based solution. Linux is often used as server OS. There *has* to be something to use from the shell, right?

Comment: NetworkManager is part of the GNOME project, and I believe this was their doing, but I can't find anything to back it up. If you don't know already, [GNOME is doing some crazy stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversy_over_GNOME_3).

Comment: I deleted `ifcfg-eth*` files from `/etc/sysconfig/network` and Network Manager began to work as it should!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Fedora, but according to [this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/the-equivalent-of-etc-network-interfaces-in-ubuntu-on-fedora-541656/), the file you are looking for should be `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-p3p1` which should look something like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=00:13:20:5E:C0:47
ONBOOT=yes
DHCP_HOSTNAME=balthasar.benhome.com
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=no
IPADDR=172.16.3.3
NETMASK=255.255.255.192
GATEWAY=172.16.3.1
```

Setting up the IP there should work.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. I read somewhere, that one should simply create a ifcfg-*interfacename*, restart network.service and edit the properties. But when I created an empty ifcfg-p3p1, network.service wouldn't start again. It is definitely enp2s5 where p3p1 is configured (the static IP address I configured there was applied to my network interface).

Comment: @wullxz yes it looks like it is enp2s5 but you had not posted the contents of that file before. Try adding `NM_CONTROLLED=no` to it which tells the interface it is not controlled by networkmanager.

Comment: how do I control it then, if NetworkManager doesn't? It has to come up automatically on reboot.

Comment: @wullxz no idea really, that's why that was just a comment. You might consider flagging this for migration to [Unix.se] you might have better chances there.

Comment: ok, will try that.

Comment: @wullxz just don't cross post, flag for moderator attention, choose other and explain that you'd like it migrated.

Comment: did that already

Comment: @wullxz You've asked this (good) question less than a day ago. It's got good responses so far, and we generally don't like to migrate questions away unless they've been sitting here without much attention or hope of getting answered for a day or two. I suggest you flag it again in a day or so if it's not resolved – just say I told you to. Thanks for your understanding.